# Multipart htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

Hey guys I'm having a bit of trouble getting my htaccess to redirect properly and was hoping for some help.

I'm expecting `DEV-domain.com?CampID=AB12345` to redirect to 
`http://DEV-www.domain.com/landing/external-marketing/direct-mail/AB?CampId=AB12345`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^DEV-(www\.)?domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^CampID=
RewriteRule (\w{2})(\w{5})$ http://DEV-www\.domain\.com/landing/external-marketing/direct-mail/$1?CampId=$1$2 [R=301,L]
```

Unfortunetly I can't get it working for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the RewriteRule matching is meant for the url path, not query strings. Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^DEV-(www\.)?domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^CampID=(\w{2})(\w{5})
RewriteRule .* http://DEV-www.domain.com/landing/external-marketing/direct-mail/%1?CampId=%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

also you don't need to escape dots `.` in the target url, only in matching patterns. And be aware that if you decide to make your target url `CampID` instead of `CampId`, you need to put in another condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/landing/external-marketing/direct-mail/
```

to avoid an infinite redirect as a target with `CampID` would match your RewriteCond rule...

Comment: Actually we can you insensitive rewriting for the match using `^(?i:campid)=(\w{2})(\w{5})` The domain HAS TO be a part of the match, so I'm not sure if I can consolidate the rewrite conditions =(